# How to determine what is being relocated using readelf

Tags: binary, elf, loader, dynamic-loading, readelf

From the snippet below, I can see that the relocation entry is to be applied at offset `0x000000201018` of some section, but how can I determine what section?

Also all of my sections are smaller than this offset. What are the implications of this?

Relocations:

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x4f8 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000201018  000300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 printk + 0
```

Section Headers:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
[ 6] .rela.plt         RELA               00000000000004f8  000004f8
     0000000000000018  0000000000000018   AI       3    21     8
...
[21] .got.plt          PROGBITS           0000000000201000  00001000
     0000000000000020  0000000000000008   WA       0     0     8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section to which the relocation is applied is specified in the `info` field of the `section headers`. From the example elf in the question, the relocation section `.rela.plt` applies to section number `21`, the `.got.plt` section.

The offset field has different meaning for object file and shared object file. "For a relocatable file, the value is the byte offset from the beginning of the section to the storage unit affected by the relocation. For an executable file or a shared object, the value is the virtual address of the storage unit affected by the relocation."

Source/More Info: http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf